# Integration testing with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Out of curiosity...
I am new to Spring Boot and I am doing some integration testing, using the newer `@SpringBootTest` annotation for the test class.

In the regular code (non-test code), the application has a custom initializer that allows it to load up external YAML files.

I wanted to make use of this in the test, so I have a `@ContextConfiguration` annotation that overrides the initializer, and likely because I added this annotation, it messes up whatever voodoo the `@SpringBootTest` is doing, so I need to add the classes parameter to give it the main `SpringApplication` so the application context is available during the test and `Autowired` beans can be found.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExamProcessorApplication.class, initializers = YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class AssessmentRepositoryImplIT {
    ...
}
```

The question I have is - is providing the `ExamProcessorApplication.class` (main SpringBootApplication) in the `@ContextConfiguration` the same - more or less - as what the default behavior `@SpringBootTest` would do during its auto-discovery?

A colleague and I were discussing this and the thought is that my way is actually instantiating the main application object but `@SpringBootTest` is not. Just trying to understand what's going on under the hood.